# How to make inner div fit 100% height to container div without touching css of container div

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem as below.
I write an UI component. This component has to fit 100% to parent div no matter how height it is and there will have more div wrapped inside it.
The thing is, I'm not allowed to update/modified the css of parent div (dynamic IDs, no class) and the component is for many different dev teams to use it.
The component is the div.content (in green color). How can I make it have full height of container div (in red color) without touching its css? Please only change the content div.

```css
.container {background-color: red; width: 500px; height: 900px;margin:auto;}
.content {background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>My Content goes here...</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you looked at flexbox?

Comment: it's seems you are trying to find a *hack* to fix a *hacky* code. I think you should revise the whole code instead because you will have more trouble if you don't start with the correct code

Comment: How do I change the style without touching the style? This question makes no sense to me. How are we supposed to restyle something if we are not allowed to touch the css? We can overwrite it with inline-css or JS/JQuery if you allowed to do that...

Comment: If you cna only change the `content` you can add extra css class like `className="full-height"` that in css will be `.full-height {height: 100%}` or something similar OR could do `style={{height: "100%"}}` regardless, you require to change the style of `content`

Answer (score 0):

Just do `.container div { height: 100%; }`. That should force all nested divs inside `.container` to grow to 100% height, and forces the green child div to fill the height of the red parent.

Of course, if you have another `<div>` elements nested at different levels (or inside `.content`, then it's a bit complicated.

See proof-of-concept example:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container div {
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="content">
              <h1>My Content goes here...</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Terry but it will affect to other divs as well. And in case of hiding, we need to re-update the height to 0. That will make lots of effort.

Comment: @HoaNguyen Then there's not much you could do. You should probably rewrite the markup so that you can style them with selectors that are not overly broad.

Comment: If there's no solution then I have to discuss more with teams. There are many onshore and offshore teams, and I really don't know what type of layout they will use for the component.

Comment: You need to understand why this is not as simple as it is: for `.content` to take up full height of its parent `.container`, all in-between divs need to occupy full height, too. Otherwise you will need to ensure that `.container` is positioned relatively, all in-between `<div>`s are statically positioned, and `.content` is positioned absolutely with an inset of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to touch other div's CSS, You can make the ".container" position be 'relative', and ".content" position as 'absolute', and then change his 'height'. Like this...

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="content">
              <h1>My Content goes here...</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="content" style="color:red;">
    <h1>My Content goes here...</h1>
</div>
```

replace your div with this

Comment: how is this even remotely suppsoed to solve the OP`s issue?

Comment: Sorry brother but I'm not allowed to do so. Other divs have its own purpose as well.

Comment: If your content is only in your h1 tag I think I can help you